# Implicit not resolved on high order function

Tags: scala, implicit

I've got a function *create* is going to provide the parameter DSLContext of `op: DSLContext => T` :

```
def create[T](op: DSLContext => T)(implicit errorHandler: Throwable => Unit):Option[T] = {
  ...
  op(new DSLContext)
  ...
}
```

Then I pass the following function to *create*:

```
def query(implicit dsl:DSLContext)
```

And here is the call

```
create(query)
```

I got this compiler error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter dsl: org.jooq.DSLContext
>   [error]     create (query)

I can resolve this issue this way : `create {implicit dsl => query}`

However i wonder why is the compiler unable to resolve the implicit parameter dsl as a given parameter ?

Comment: You need ``DSLContext => T``, you pass ``DSLContext`` and get an error. When you pass ``DSLContext => T``, no error. What is wrong?

Comment: Same. Not quite sure what you're expecting.

Comment: @JeanLogeart query is DSLContext => T, not just a DSLContext. So when I pass query as parameter of create, I pass a function taking a DSLContext and returning T.

Comment: He wants to pass a method reference instead of an anonymous function to `create`. `query` is that method. In other words, he wants to partially apply a method with an implicit argument, and this is where the compiler gets confused.

Comment: @Hexx I suggest you modify `query` to take a normal (non-implicit) argument, and assign it to a local `implicit val`. `def query(dsl: DSLContext) = { implicit val idsl = dsl; ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that when you pass a method where a function is expected the compiler needs to perform an eta-expansion to convert it.

In other words the method `query` needs to become a `Function1[DSLContext, T]`.

However, the compiler needs to resolve the implicit parameter in order to be able to apply the eta-expansion. In your case there's no `DSLContext` in scope, so the compiler fails in doing so.

You can reproduce this behavior with a simpler example, here's a REPL session demonstrating it:

```
scala> def foo(implicit i: Int) = "hello"
foo: (implicit i: Int)String

scala> foo _
<console>:10: error: could not find implicit value for parameter i: Int
              foo _
              ^

scala> implicit val x = 5
x: Int = 5

scala> foo _
res3: scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString = hello
```

where `_` manually triggers the eta-expansion.

For the record, this is described in the [language reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), paragraph 6.26.2.

> If the method takes only implicit parameters, implicit arguments are passed following the rules of §7.2.